# Is it UB to cast a pointer to a void pointer and write to it?

Tags: c, arrays, macros, undefined-behavior, dynamic-arrays

I was working on a way to create dynamic arrays in C, and I came up with this solution as a general structure for how I want my functions/macros to work:

```
//dynarray.h
#define dynarray(TYPE)\
    struct{\
        TYPE *data;\
        size_t size;\
        size_t capacity;\
    }

int dynarray_init_internal(void **ptr, size_t *size, size_t *cap, size_t type_size, size_t count);

#define dynarray_init(ARR, SIZE) dynarray_init_internal(&ARR->data, &ARR->size, &ARR->capacity, sizeof(*ARR->data), SIZE)

//dynarray.c
int dynarray_init_internal(void **ptr, size_t *size, size_t *cap, size_t type_size, size_t count){
    *ptr = malloc(type_size*count);
    if(*ptr == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    *size = 0;
    *cap = count;
    return 1;
}
```

Is this an acceptable approach to have a generic function/macro combo that deals with dynamically allocating memory in a type agnostic way?

The only doubts I have about this is that I'm not sure if this is undefined behavior or not. I imagine this could be easily expanded for other functions that are typically expected for a dynamic array structure. The only issue I can see with it is that since it's an anonymous struct you can't pass it as an argument anywhere (easily at least), but that can be easily fixed by creating a `dynarray_def(TYPE, NAME)` macro which would define a dynamic array struct with `NAME` and have it hold data of `TYPE` while still having it work with all the other function/macro style listed above.

Comment: You cannot pass `TYPE**` to `void**`, this shouldn't even compile.

Comment: There have been systems where `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(int*)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undefined behavior because you're converting (for example) an `int **` to a `void **` and dereferencing it to yield a `void *`.  The automatic conversion to/from a `void *` does *not* extend to `void **`.  Reading/writing one type as another (in this case, writing a `int *` as a `void *`) is in violation.

The best way to handle this is to make the entire init routine a macro:

```
#define dynarray_init(ARR, SIZE) \
do {\
    (ARR)->data = malloc(sizeof(*(ARR)->data*(SIZE));\
    if ((ARR)->data == NULL){\
        _exit(1);\
    }\
    (ARR)->size = 0;\
    (ARR)->capacity = (SIZE);\
} while (0)
```

EDIT:

If you're looking to shy away from function-like macros, you can instead use a macro to create a function and the struct type it works with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define dynarray(TYPE)\
struct dynarray_##TYPE {\
    TYPE *data;\
    size_t size;\
    size_t capacity;\
};\
\
int dynarray_##TYPE##_init(struct dynarray_##TYPE **ptr, size_t count){\
    *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr)*count);\
    if(*ptr == NULL){\
        return 1;\
    }\
    \
    (*ptr)->size = 0;\
    (*ptr)->capacity = count;\
    return 1;\
}

// generate types and functions    
dynarray(int)
dynarray(double)

int main()
{
    struct dynarray_int *da1;
    dynarray_int_init(&da1, 5);
    // use da1
    struct dynarray_double *da2;
    dynarray_double_init(&da2, 5);
    // use da2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to do this specifically to avoid using function-like macros. The only other solution I've got is to have my macro generate functions but I don't like that much either, but I'll probably end up going with it if I really can't figure out another way to do this.

Comment: @zee See my edit.  You can use macros to generate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Because some rare implementations use different representations for different types of pointers, the Standard does not require that implementations allow them to be manipulated interchangeably.  Instead, it regards support for such manipulation as a "popular extension" for which support is a "Quality of Implementation" issue outside its jurisdiction.  Just about any compiler for a remotely-commonplace platform will be configurable to support the construct, and the while the authors of the Standard wanted to give programmers a "fighting chance" [their words] to write portable code, they have explicitly said they did not wish to "demean" programs that weren't 100% portable.

Note, however, that some optimizers are unable to handle such constructs except by completely disabling type-based aliasing analysis is disabled, and any program that is using such constructs will need to document such requirement.  On the other hand, unless one needs to target obscure architectures, it's often better to use constructs and document their usage is often better than to jump through hoops to accommodate poor quality optimizers.

Note, btw, that even good quality compilers could get tripped up by some sufficiently-tricky usage patterns involving pointer casts.  The authors of the Standard didn't want to forbid implementations from performing useful optimizations merely because some tricky and contrived usage patterns could yield incorrect behavior, but they expected that implementations would be able to recognize patterns their users would actually use.  For example, given:

```
float f;
int *ip; float *fp;
int *ipp = (int**)(&fp);
...
void test(void)
{
  fp = &f;
  f = 1.0;
  **ip+=1;
  return f;
}
```

a compiler would have no realistic way of recognizing that a write to `**ip` could realistically affect an object of type `float`.  If, however, the address of `fp` had been stored into `ip` between the write to `f` and the later read therefrom, optimizing compilers in the era when the Standard was written would recognize that converting a `T*` to a `U*` should be regarded as a potential memory clobber on any object of type `T*` that might be accessed via the `U*`.  I suspect your usage patterns fit the latter pattern far more strongly than the former.

```
*ipp = someFloat;
```